# Images not showing in Vue-CoolLightBox component in Nuxt App

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js, lightbox

I wrote this code to use Vue-CoolLightBox in my Nuxt App.
I installed this in my Nuxt app using `npm install --save vue-cool-lightbox`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <CoolLightBox 
      :items="items" 
      :index="index"
      @close="index = null">
    </CoolLightBox>

    <div class="images-wrapper">
      <div
        class="image"
        v-for="(image, imageIndex) in items"
        :key="imageIndex"
        @click="index = imageIndex"
        :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + image + ')' }"
      ></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      images: [
        'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg',
        'https://static.toiimg.com/photo/72975551.cms',
      ],
      index: null
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

The problem is that the images are not loading in page or the images array is not binding with component items. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

I think you didn't import your component in your Vue instance.

```
<script>
import CoolLightBox from 'vue-cool-lightbox'

export default {
  components: {
    CoolLightBox
  },
  data() {
    return {
      images: [
        'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg',
        'https://static.toiimg.com/photo/72975551.cms',
      ],
      index: null
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Is this code working ?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: just updated the link, sorry I messed up with it even if it was already working, wanted to remove the un-useful files.

Here is a working example on what you're trying to do: https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxt-vue-cool-lightbox-working-roc36?file=/pages/index.vue

It was missing some linking to `images` rather than `items` and a bit of CSS. At least, if you imported everything else as explained in the [official repo documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cool-lightbox).

Here is the code that is important

```html
<CoolLightBox :items="images" :index="index" @close="index = null">
</CoolLightBox>

<div class="images-wrapper">
  <div
    class="image"
    v-for="(image, imageIndex) in images"
    :key="imageIndex"
    @click="index = imageIndex"
    :style="{ backgroundImage: `url(${image})` }"
  ></div>
</div>
```